# Process of other language's character failed

Tags: php, character-encoding

What my php page does.

- A post request comes from other site and it may contain text in language other then english.
- Now I am sending this content to GoogleSpreadsheet but here the other language character becomes ?(question mark).
- I have set header to UTF-8 but still not worked

Can anyone help ??

Code snippet :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$name= $_POST['name'];
$row=array('no'=>123,'name'=>$name);
$listFeed->insert($row);
```

Comment: How do you do this? Be more accurate ***by editing your question*** pls

Comment: I have edited the question. Added code snippet for understanding